# cursor-size change with dconf-editor not saved on reboot

Tags: dconf

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and have added the below config:

```
$ cat  /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00_default-interface 
/org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size
```

I have changed cursor-size from 24 to 60, and run `sudo dconf update`. It works fine for the session, but after a reboot, the setting is not saved.